# Changing order of fields in Drupal's blog

Tags: drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and Zircon template. I am trying to change the order of fields of my blog. Basically, my blog shows (in front page):

Title
Date/Time
Body
Link to "Read more"

I created some categories using taxonomy and I want to show this category before the title.

In "Manage Display" from "Administration » Structure » Content types » Blog entry" I can just put the category after or before the Body field. I think I will need to change something in the code, but I don't know where. I found the file "field--taxonomy-term-reference.tpl.php" where I can customise some information about category, but not where it will appear.

Does anybody knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module else with coding you can override node template.

Cheers!!!